# VBA automatically converting my range to absolute values when I use a relative range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where I use several named ranges in a formula. These named ranges have relative references in them. Every year I have to go about copying the sheet, remove old names, and assign new ones. I'm trying to get the whole workbook to do all this programatically to save time.

I'm trying to avoid having to use the offset function and anything I find online only tells me how to convert it with a function but for formulas (not a range as I need.) The code below takes my range and makes them all absolute. How do I get them to stay relative? I've tried R1C1 which I think is only valid on a formula anyway. The site I used as a start to my code was: https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-create-named-range/

```
Option Explicit

Sub createNamedRange()  'https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-create-named-range/
Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Byte
Dim myNamedRange As Range
Dim myRangeName As String

Set myWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")     'identify worksheet containing cell range, and cell range itself (below)...

For i = 1 To 12         'i represents each month. we'll set range dependent upon month

Select Case i

Case Is = 1
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B8")

Case Is = 2
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B14,B8")

Case Is = 3
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B20,B14,B8")

Case Is = 4
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B30,B20,B14,B8")

Case Is = 5
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B36,B30,B20,B14,B8")

Case Is = 6
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B42,B36,B30,B20,B14,B8")

Case Is = 7
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B52,B42,B36,B30,B20,B14,B8")

Case Is = 8
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B58,B52,B42,B36,B30,B20,B14,B8")

Case Is = 9
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B64,B58,B52,B42,B36,B30,B20,B14,B8")

Case Is = 10
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B74,B64,B58,B52,B42,B36,B30,B20,B14,B8")

Case Is = 11
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B80,B74,B64,B58,B52,B42,B36,B30,B20,B14,B8")

Case Is = 12
    Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range("B86,B80,B74,B64,B58,B52,B42,B36,B30,B20,B14,B8")
End Select

myRangeName = MonthName(i) & "Denominator2019"      'specify defined name
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersTo:=myNamedRange    'create named range with workbook scope. Defined name and cell range are as specified

Next i      'run back through loop and complete other months

End Sub
```

Comment: try something like`RefersTo:=Range(myNamedRange.Address(0,0))`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I tried that as written and get the same thing: absolute ranges. I then tried to replace the 0s with values greater than 0 but same thing.

Comment: See "using relative references" http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/naming_techniques/   Try recording a macro while following the steps and look at what you get - that should give you a starting point.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have tried this and still get absolute references. I tried changing just the "refersto" to "referstor1c1" and got absolute references. So then I went up and changed my "set mynamedrange" statement to "Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Cells(8, 2)" along with the referstor1c1 still on the bottom and once again, I still get absolute references.

Answer (score 3):

Recording a macro while adding a relative named range I get this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="test4", _
                         RefersToR1C1:= "=Sheet1!R[1]C,Sheet1!R[1]C[2],Sheet1!R[1]C[4]"
```

When creating the name I had B10 selected, and for the range address I added "B11,D11,F11"

Maybe you could explain a little exactly how you want to use your relative range?

EDIT: something like this -

```
Sub createNamedRanges()  'https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-create-named-range/
    Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim myNamedRange As Range, sRng As String, arr
    Dim myRangeName As String, sep As String

    Set myWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    arr = Split("B86,B80,B74,B64,B58,B52,B42,B36,B30,B20,B14,B8", ",") 'array(0 to 11)

    sRng = ""
    sep = ""
    For i = 1 To 12

        sRng = arr(11 - (i - 1)) & sep & sRng
        sep = "," 'add separator after first loop pass
        Set myNamedRange = myWorksheet.Range(sRng)
        myRangeName = MonthName(i) & "Denominator2019"

        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, _
                RefersToR1C1:=myNamedRange.Address(False, False, xlR1C1, True)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I needed to get rid of the set mynamedrange statements altogether it looks like. Still rewriting it all and will post what I came up with. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's exactly what I was trying to do:

```
Sub createNamedRange()

Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Byte
Dim myRangeName As String

Set myWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")     'identify worksheet containing cell range, and cell range itself (below)...

myWorksheet.Range("B1").Select

For i = 1 To 12         'i represents each month. we'll set range dependent upon month

myRangeName = MonthName(i) & "Denominator2019"      'specify defined name

Select Case i

Case Is = 1
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[7]C"    'create named range with workbook scope. Must use r1c1 for relative references.

Case Is = 2
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"

Case Is = 3
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[19]C,Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"

Case Is = 4
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[29]C,Sheet1!R[19]C,Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"

Case Is = 5
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[35]C,Sheet1!R[29]C,Sheet1!R[19]C,Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"

Case Is = 6
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[41]C,Sheet1!R[35]C,Sheet1!R[29]C,Sheet1!R[19]C,Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"

Case Is = 7
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[51]C,Sheet1!R[41]C,Sheet1!R[35]C,Sheet1!R[29]C,Sheet1!R[19]C,Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"

Case Is = 8
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[57]C,Sheet1!R[51]C,Sheet1!R[41]C,Sheet1!R[35]C,Sheet1!R[29]C,Sheet1!R[19]C,Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"

Case Is = 9
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[63]C,Sheet1!R[57]C,Sheet1!R[51]C,Sheet1!R[41]C,Sheet1!R[35]C,Sheet1!R[29]C,Sheet1!R[19]C,Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"

Case Is = 10
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[73]C,Sheet1!R[63]C,Sheet1!R[57]C,Sheet1!R[51]C,Sheet1!R[41]C,Sheet1!R[35]C,Sheet1!R[29]C,Sheet1!R[19]C,Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"

Case Is = 11
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[79]C,Sheet1!R[73]C,Sheet1!R[63]C,Sheet1!R[57]C,Sheet1!R[51]C,Sheet1!R[41]C,Sheet1!R[35]C,Sheet1!R[29]C,Sheet1!R[19]C,Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"

Case Is = 12
    myWorksheet.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R[85]C,Sheet1!R[79]C,Sheet1!R[73]C,Sheet1!R[63]C,Sheet1!R[57]C,Sheet1!R[51]C,Sheet1!R[41]C,Sheet1!R[35]C,Sheet1!R[29]C,Sheet1!R[19]C,Sheet1!R[13]C,Sheet1!R[7]C"
End Select

Next i      'run back through loop and complete other months

End Sub
```

Comment: please credit @TimWilliams by accepting his answer, as that is what led you to your solution